# Debug unavailable on Android device (U8500) though code is executable there

Tags: android, debugging

I've just faced a tricky thing with my Android device (Huawei U8500) - it doesn't seem to send any debug data at all. I cannot see anything through logcat in Eclipse nor through ddms.

Steps taken:

1. Android SDK installed, Eclipse installed
2. Enabled USB Debugging on my device
3. Enabled debugging in AndroidManifest.xml
4. Installed device drivers
5. Connected device via USB

I am allowed to run project on my handset through Eclipse and everything works fine. I see the device in "Android Device Chooser" but there`s a blank field in "debug" field, though the same field for emulator says "Yes". There's no debug information when I run project on device not in Eclipse nor ddms.

Rebooted device and PC several times, doesn`t seem to fix that.

Maybe you could share some ideas how to solve the issue or that`s a device problem cannot be solved?

Comment: try running `adb shell logcat`, can you see logs?

Comment: adb -d shell logcat works, still nothing in Eclipse

Comment: thanks, at least that will do

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell
echo 1 > /sys/kernel/logger/log_main/enable
```